# Mostrar resultado json concreto

Tags: json, curl

Estoy intentando mostrar únicamente un valor con el siguiente comando:

```
curl -X GET -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"state": "on"}' http://${HUE}/api/${API}/lights/1
```

Pero el resultado me muestra todo la respuesta JSON.
No puedo mostrar el resultado que estoy intentando recuperar únicamente (**'{"state": "on"}'**) ?

```
{"state":{"on":true,"bri":90,"alert":"select","mode":"homeautomation","reachable":true},"swupdate":{"state":"noupdates","lastinstall":"2019-01-04T22:37:21"},"type":"Dimmable light","name":"Bombeta menjador 1","modelid":"LWB010","manufacturername":"Philips","productname":"Hue white lamp","capabilities":{"ce...
```

Como puedo mostrar el resultado que intento filtrar? Debería ser **true**/**false**

gracias!

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. En la petición cURL se ve que ya conoces el dato `'{"state": "on"}'`, ¿para qué quieres sólo *recuperar*  algo que ya conoces antes de enviar la petición?

Comment: quiero recuperar solo ese parametro. no obtener toda la salida

Comment: Eso depende de cómo esté programa la API. Si observas: `http://${HUE}/api/${API}/lights/1` se puede entender que la API tiene lo que se llama *puntos de entrada* (`lights` sería uno). Por ejemplo, imaginemos que `user` es un punto de entrada, la API podría tener una URL como `user/alldata/id/1` que traería todos los datos (`alldata`)  del usuario `1`. Y podría tener otra URL como `user/status/1` que te traería solamente el `status` del usuario `1`. O sea, tienes que dotar a la API de esa posibilidad (si eres el programador de la misma) o investigar cómo consultarla, si una API de terceros.